# How to get information from a GraphQL query that accepts no arguments

Tags: graphql

## The situation

I have inherited a project that pulls from a GraphpQL API hosted somewhere on AWS.
I knew nothing about GraphQL yesterday morning, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I have *almost* all of the queries I need working, except one that looks odd.
`Query -> pullUserData` accepts no arguments, and returns the `UserData` type.

Nothing I try can get a record from this query. Even though the UserData seems to be pulled elsewhere in the project.

All of my searching for an answer just gets results for how_to(pass_args:to_a_query).

## What I've tried.

I have attempted many variations of the following.
I'm using `__typename` in the examples because (I think?) every field has a typename.

`{ pullUserData(id:"known_id") { __typename } }`
And I get back a validation error "unknown field argument", which makes sense, the schema said it accepts no args.

`{ pullUserData }`
Validation Error, subselection required. Again, kindof what I was expecting.

`{ pullUserData { __typename } }`
This get some more information:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "pullUserData"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "Lambda:Unhandled",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Unable to parse event"
    }
  ]
}
```

## In summary

I'm trying to pull data from a query that accepts no args, and can't figure it out.

I think I inherited this from someone who left on bad terms. Either way, they will not communicate with me or the company.

I learned what little I know of GraphQL on this project, yesterday, and I feel like I'm missing something that will be obvious to anyone who has used it before.
I'm starting to suspect it's just broken, too.

Thanks for any help y'all can give.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
query { 
    pullUserData {
         // fields you want to get
    }
}
```

If the query has no arguments, there is no need for parentheses at all.

However, you need to specify the properties you want to get from the query.

If you can run the graphql server locally, it should allow you to visit a 'playground' where you can test the queries and mutations.

Comment: That's the third example of what I tried, making a subselection returns the error statement, not making it returns a validation error.